# Javascript object array sort by date not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date

I have a javascript object array with 5 items in it. Each has a field which is the date field. The date format is as follows: `Mon Dec 17 2018 19:28:29 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) {}`

When I try this:
 `myArray.sort(function(a, b) { return b.CreateTime - a.CreateTime ;})`

The array is not sorted, ie, the object with the earliest CreateTime field value is not either at the top or bottom, it is in the middle.

I tried also this:

`myArray.sort(function(a, b) { return (new Date(b.CreateTime.getTime())) - (new Date(a.CreateTime.getTime())) ;})`

Didn't work.

Also tried this:

`myArray.sort(function(a, b) { return (new Date(b.CreateTime)) - (new Date(a.CreateTime)) ;})`

Still no go.

Online searches say this IS the way to sort an array of JS objects by date.

So, what am I missing?

Here is a sample object:

```
{
 "Identifier": "prd17865EXC",
 "Type": "large",
 "Status": "available",
 "UN": "u367892",
 "DBN": "sprtdb",
 "EP": {
         "Prod": "excersizeMachine1",
         "Number": 57477367
       },
 "CreateTime": "2018-12-18T00:28:29.803Z"
}
```

Comment: What is `CreateTime`and what ***exactly*** does it return?

Comment: What is the key in your object for the date ? object.date ? Please show us some of this objects

Comment: CreateTime is the date field

Comment: This is the key: b.CreateTime

Comment: shouldn't this be `new Date(b.CreateTime).getTime()` instead of `new Date(b.CreateTime.getTime())`?

Comment: It is a top-level field, not nested

Comment: @Kenobi the question is, what **exactly** do those strings/numbers look like? Like, **post** the content here.

Comment: Is the CreateTime field a javascript `Date` object ?

Comment: It returns this: Mon Dec 17 2018 19:28:29 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) {}

Comment: So are the values *strings* of that form? Or are they Date instances? All this would be *much* easier if you'd simple extend the content of your question with more contextual information.

Comment: Can you please give us the output of `myArray.map(function(a){return JSON.stringify(a.CreateTime);});`

Comment: They are date instances as they give me date functions to select when I debug.

Comment: If they're date instances, then `typeof a.CreateTime` would be `"object"`. Strings like that cannot be reliably parsed as dates, especially with that stray `{}` at the end.

Comment: When I stringify, I get this: ""2018-12-18T00:28:29.803Z""

Comment: If they're *really* date instances then `b.CreateTime - a.CreateTime` would definitely work.

Comment: I have stringified one of the objects and posted above.

Comment: Unless you give us a minimum example, we won't be able to help. You must provide the content of myArray in a way that you can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have a typo there in the second approach.
You want to call `getTime()` on a newly created date, not your initial date.

It should be:

```
myArray.sort(function(a, b) {
  return new Date(b.CreateTime).getTime() - new Date(a.CreateTime).getTime();
});
```

Comment: You don't really need the calls to `.getTime()` because the date instances will convert to numbers for the `-` operation, but it doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: @Pointy: good point, it's just more explicit instead of relying on JS's magical casting system ;)

Comment: Tried that, still no go.

Comment: I have stringified one of the objects and posted above.

Comment: I just used your new code snippet and the code I posted sorts the objects in the descending order

Comment: "I believe you have a typo…" that's a reason to close. ;-) Also, you should point out what the typo is.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let myArray = [{
  CreateTime :"2018-12-18T00:28:29.803Z"
  },
  {
  CreateTime :"2018-12-16T00:28:29.803Z"
  }
];

myArray.sort( (a,b) => {
  dateA = new Date(a.CreateTime);
  dateB = new Date(b.CreateTime);
  
  return dateA - dateB;
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: I have stringified one of the objects and posted above.